# Laravel Form and tables with relationships

Tags: laravel, forms, eloquent, relationship

Hi i have 4 tables Customers / Refunds / Refunds_Services / Services I cannot send correctly parameters from a form submittion. The 3 models are : 
Customer model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customers extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'contr_nom',
        'contr_cog',
        'benef_nom',
        'benef_cog',
        'email',
        'polizza',
        'targa',
        'data_sin',
        'iban',
        'int_iban',
        'dossier',
        'cliente',
        ];

        public function refunds()
            {
                return $this->hasMany(Refunds::class);
                //return $this->belongsToMany(Services::class)->withPivot(['services_id','importo','data_ric']);
            }       

        }
```

Refunds model

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Refunds extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'date_ref',
        'status_ref',
        ];

        public function services()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Services::class)->withPivot(['services_id','services_amount','services_status']);
        }       

        public function customers()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Customers::class);
        }
```

Services model

```
   <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Services extends Model
{
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'code',
        'name',
    ];

    public function refunds()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Refunds::class);
    }

}
```

Customer table store customer datas and each customer can do various refunds requests (with own date and status) . Any Refunds request can have multiple services with own import, date and so on. All these i put in a form. There are customers datas text boxes and a button that can add services .

Then each time u press all form Save button u made one Refund request. in my controller i did this method trying to store datas in all different tables

```
$customers = Customers::create($request->all());

        $tipo = $request->input('tipo', []);
        $importo = $request->input('importo', []);

        for ($i=0; $i < count($tipo); $i++) {
            if ($tipo[$i] != '') {
                $test = $customers->refunds();
                $test->services()->attach($tipo[$i], [
                'services_id' => $tipo[$i],
                'importo' => $importo[$i]
                ]);
            }
        }                       

        return redirect("/");
```

Customers data are saved but i cannot access to bridge table refunds_services to store the services of the refunds request. In effect I also have to store refund request datas in refunds table. How can i do? Thx a lot

Comment: How did you want to access the refunds when you have just created your customer?

Comment: infact this is my question i thought something like this $customers->refunds()->services(). Because when a datas are send customers data has to be saved in customer tables, date_ref, status_ref in refunds table and the other in a table called refunds_services. I dunno how to do. i need to use create method but  i dunno how thx

Comment: Then you need to create a new refund first then you can access the service.

Comment: In your Refund model, **replace** belongsToMany with `hasMany`. Give this a shot and let us know.